# What's the best way to import such dataset?

Tags: import, data, dataset, data-structures

> https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/400305-large-data-set-lds_1-h630-2018-h640-2018-2019-pre-release-data-mei.xlsx

What's the best way to import such dataset?

I have tried to use

```
dat2 = Import[   "https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/400305-large-data-set-lds_1-h630-\ 2018-h640-2018-2019-pre-release-data-mei.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Data"}]
```

which looks ok.

But is there a better way to import this as some kind of `DataSet`? So I can then call it like

```
dat2["Swaziland"]
```

or using the ID

```
dat2["50"]
```

ect.

Also how can I make full use of the `Headings`? Deal with the `missing data`? At the moment, there are simply shown as `, , , ,`

What is it with the `$Failed`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Import[
    "https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/400305-large-data-set-lds_1-h630-2018-h640-2018-2019-pre-release-data-mei.xlsx", 
    {"Dataset", "Data"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1
]
```

Though there's a bug in getting headers in 11.3 that is fixed in the next version. To get around this bug, please use this workaround:

```
Import["https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/400305-large-data-set-lds_1-h630-2018-h640-2018-2019-pre-release-data-mei.xlsx", 
    {"Dataset", "Data"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1
] /. System`Convert`ExcelDump`null -> ""
```

The "" can be replaced with any other value you would like to use in place of the null symbol that is appearing. You could also add another replacement rule for `$Failed` as well. I will look into why these cells are imported as `$Failed`. The `$Failed` appears to be from `=#N/A`, which is the correct output.

Comment: I got quite a lot of `StringLength::string: String expected at position 1 in StringLength[System`Convert`ExcelDump`null].` errors ..

Comment: Sorry, this is a bug in 11.3 that is fixed in the next version that has yet to be released. In the meantime, I edited my answer with a workaround.